# Strange Swift behaviour when using objc_getAssociatedObject()

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift-playground

The behaviour can be observed by placing this code in a playground:

```
import Foundation
import ObjectiveC

class TestClass {}
var obj = TestClass()

let stringValue = "xyz"
let key = "def"

objc_setAssociatedObject(obj, key, stringValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)

//let f = "f"
let returnedString = objc_getAssociatedObject(obj, key)
```

This works and returns "xyz" from the `objc_getAssociatedObject` call.

However, if you remove the comment from the `let f = "f"` line. The `objc_getAssociatedObject` call now returns nil.

I'm baffled as to how setting a totally unrelated variable can effect the call.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which Xcode version are you running?

Comment: I can reproduce this in a 7.1.1 playground, but not in an actual application. Playground bug perhaps.

Comment: I was thinking about that. Also, if you put the definition between the keys and runtime calls it breaks. If you move the let f = "f" up, it works just fine.

Comment: The code I posted is a reduction from code I had in a unit test. In the test I was testing some code that added an associated property. So I wanted to get the value I had stored to check it was correct. But I kept getting nils back even when I modified the code I was testing to return the key used to store the value. I know the value was being stored because other code was quite happily using the value later. So I cut-n-pasted into a playground to see what was happening and ended up with the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug.

The objc_... methods are part of the Objective-C runtime. They *shouldn't* exist in Swift.

That said they clearly do. So my guess is that there's something happening when you set that method that kicks the runtime, similar to calling `synchronize` on NSUserDefaults.

**Edit:** [This NSHipster article](http://nshipster.com/swift-objc-runtime/) explains that the ObjC runtime is actually there.

**Edit 2:** I tried a few experiments, and I'll make your question even weirder. Wrapping the test case inside the object yields the same result. But changing the variable name to an underscore fixes the problem:

```
let _ = "f"
```

I bet assigning a variable overwrites whatever runtime associations you set manually. The underscore just tells the compiler that you aren't using the result of the assignment.

Comment: If changing the variable name to an underscore fixes the problem, this indicates that the playground machinery is likely interfering with the Objective-C runtime machinery (or the compiler's registration of the class with the runtime). Xcode invisibly rewrites your code, adding logging functions to drive the results sidebar. When you assign to `_`, that particular line of code is not rewritten. I suggest filing a bug report (and responding with the # here for the record).

Comment: I'm not the OP, but that's what my poking suggests, but I'm still unsure what exact semantic meaning of that underscore is. Everyone I've asked just says "it means that you're not using the variable" but what does that mean to the Swift compiler?

Comment: See my above comment to. I originally hit this bug in a unit test and moved it to a playground when attempting to figure out what was going on. I don't know if it exists inside the app because my original code didn't actually attempt to retrieve the value. Only the unit test did.